# ios/objective-c/core-data: How to show relationship as property in NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, objective-c, relationship, nsmanagedobject

I have two entities and have just created a 1:1 relationship between them.  There are subclasses for the entities but they have a lot of code in them at this point so I don't want to use Xcode to automatically generate new NSManagedObject subclasses.

Instead, I thought I could just reference the relationship with a property in each one.  I did that and it seemed to work for a while but now it is throwing mysterious errors and I can't seem to get rid of them.  I have imported the reciprocal of each one but it is not helping.  Can anyone recommend what I should do?  Many thanks in advance.

```
Subclassed NSManagedObjects (simplified)

//Items.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "Notes.h"

@interface Items : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *iid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *item;

//this is relationship
@property (nonatomic, retain) Notes *note;
//above throws error Unkown Type Name 'Notes'
@end

//Notes.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "Items.h"

@interface Notes : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * nid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * note;

//this is relationship
@property (nonatomic, retain) Items *item;
//above throws error Unkown Type Name 'Item'
@end
```

This is similar to relationship

[image]

Comment: Why are you using retains are you not using ARC (use nonatomic, strong instead if you are)?

Comment: @Ron I assume he's using retain because the classes generated by Xcode still use retain for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying it both ways as error for another configuration mentioned strong but will use strong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C you can't use a type before it is declared.  To fix this you can use a forward declaration of your classes by putting these lines below the `#import` statements and above the first `@interface`.

```
@class Items;
@class Notes;
```

If your posted code is not representative of your actual file structure (which I assume it isn't), you'll have to put the `@class` statement for `Items` in the Notes.h file and the `@class` statement for `Notes` in the Items.h file.

Comment: For some reason I thought it had to be one or the other import or class.  But this did the trick. Thx!

Comment: Your `#import` statements just include the contents of some other file, which may or may not include declarations that you need for your content.  If they do not include the declarations you need, the `@class` or `@protocol` statements can be used as well.